# conda does not update to 23.5.0

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

My `conda` won't update anymore. Why? What can I do?

While doing a `conda update --all` on one of my environments, I got the occasional

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.3.1
  latest version: 23.5.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=23.5.0
```

So, as usual, I deactivated my current environment an did the `conda update -n base -c defaults conda`.

Strangely, the latter command runs smoothly, once again telling me that a newer version of `conda` exists and that I should update **and** then ... it just terminates with

```
# All requested packages already installed.
```

After that, `conda` is still not updated. When I try a somewhat more forceful approach by doing

```
conda install -n base -c defaults 'conda>=23.5.0'
```

my machine goes into outer space for several hours, failing initial frozen solve, retrying flexible solve, analyzing conflicts, etc., seemingly without success ... until I stop the process with `CTRL C`

I do have (only) two environments, i.e., `base` and `evb`. With `conda list` the former one shows a `conda 23.3.1` the latter one a `conda 23.5.0`. The only environment I keep up to date with `conda update --all` is the `evb` one.

So, now I'm stuck. Any suggestions would be welcome.

(B.t.w. I'm also confused why the 'non-base' environment contains a most recent `conda`. Does `conda update --all` within an environment also update the `conda` of that environment? And if so, why care about the `conda` of the base at all? But anyway, that is not the issue of this post.)

Comment: There should not be a `conda` in the non-base env

Comment: I was also guessing so when adding the (B.t.w. ...) section to my post. Yet, I have zero ideas, how it got there - let alone, if keeping or removing it would cause any trouble either way, or if it can just stay as an irrelevant bunch of bytes on my disk.

Answer (score 2):

One possible cause of this issue is conflicts with packages from other channels. For me, the culprit was `mamba` from the `conda-forge`-channel which is installed in the base environment on purpose.

To check if you have packages from other channels, run

```
conda list -n base
```

To get allow the resolver to access `conda-forge` (or other non-default channels), add the channels after `defaults`:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults -c conda-forge conda
```

Comment: Confirming that ```conda update -n base -c defaults -c conda-forge conda``` worked.
I am using miniconda, and it refused to update from 4.12 to 23.7

Answer (score 1):

Answering your own question, likely, is never an optimal practice, but for the record, I eventually found a workaround:

1. For the purpose of solving the issue, drop the `.condarc` file momentarily by renaming it.
2. Activate the base, i.e., `conda activate base` and do a `conda update --all`.

This *did* update the base environment *and* the `conda` version contained in base. Following that, I put my `.condarc` back into place. Subsequent updates of my actual environment for work did not complain about the need to update conda anymore.

So, case closed ... at least until next `conda` update

Comment: You are mistaken. It is actually encouraged to answer your own question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow

Comment: The question is though, what is in your `.condarc`. Have you defined additional channels and set channel priorities?